# Performance of JSoup and Bitmap Images

Tags: java, android, html, bitmap, jsoup

I've been working on an Android app where I am getting an RSS feed and I need to parse some additional HTML for image source links. So, I figured I would use JSoup and see how it went. It IS working and I can get the image src link correctly. However the .Parse method is taking a very long time to complete and I can't have the user waiting that long. All of this fetching of the RSS takes place in onStart() in the app by the way.

My ultimate goal is to retrieve the images from the src url's and display them next to article text. I've had my fair share of dealing with the common OutOfMemory errors in relation to the heap. As of now I seem to have sort of dealt with it. But I still cannot figure out why the loading of the program is taking so long. Right now there are 10 articles in the RSS feed and the HTML parsing for each one is not really long. Maybe someone can spot something stupid I'm doing and figure out why the loading of my program is taking so long. I would certainly appreciate it! Here is my code involving the images and Jsoup.

```
 public static Bitmap parseForImg(String desc) throws IOException
    {


        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(desc);

        Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
        String imgURL = "";
        Bitmap img = null;

        if(images.size() > 0)
        {
        for (Element image : images)
        {
            imgURL = image.attr("src");
            break;
        }

        String editedImgURL = imgURL.replace("/sites/", "https://www.").trim();
        img = ArticleRSSReader.grabImgFromURL(editedImgURL);

        }
        else
        {
            //in the event there is no image related to a description in the rss feed, just display
            //the logo for now...
            InputStream inputS = MainActivity.globalTHIS.getResources().getAssets().open("defaultlogo.png");
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputS);
            //no need to grab image from url, just return 


        }



        return img;
    }

    public static Bitmap grabImgFromURL(String imageURLLoc)
    {
        URL imageURL = null;
        Bitmap resizedBit = null;

        try
        {
            imageURL = new URL(imageURLLoc);
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);// Convert to
                                                                // bitmap
            // image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            options.inPurgeable = true;


            resizedBit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options), 100, 100, false);


        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resizedBit;
    }
```

Comment: I figure that it takes 1 second to parse the first image url from the HTML, 1 second to grab the image from the url, then 1 second to rescale the image. Multiply that by 10 images and you get 30 seconds. I have no idea what could be taking that long or how to speed this process up.

Comment: Perhaps if this takes some time then I need to cache these images for the first time and then every time after I will have them. If new things are added from the RSS feed then that will be for a smaller amount.